# Embedding an image into CV in LaTex

Tags: moderncv, wrapfigure

I have been trying to embed my photo into upper right corner of my CV with the wrapfig package. But it doesn't work the right way and the surrounding text migrates to the far right. How should I fix it?

Script is shown below

````
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  %Windows 
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[top=0.7cm, bottom=0.8cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{times}


\firstname{Rostislav}
\familyname{Erzin}
\title{} 

\begin{wrapfigure}{T}{0.15\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{Polar.jpg} 
\end{wrapfigure}

\address{Marseille, France}{}  
\mobile{}
%\phone{}                
%\fax{Votre Fax}                      
\email{erzinrost@gmail.com}
\social[linkedin]{rostislav-erzin}
\social[github]{Erzinrost}```
````

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: You do not need wrapfigure.  Just add `\photo[2cm]{Polar.jpg}` instead, to put a 2cm wide figure in the upper right corner

Comment: Great, thank you so much. Turned out to be way easier than imagined.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is solved in comments ...